# What does it mean when a variable is both __block and __weak in ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I understand that __block in ARC retains the variable. This can then be used when accessing a variable within a block before the variable has been assigned, as in:

```
  __block __weak id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notif){
    // reference the observer here. observer also retains this block,
    // so we'd have a retain cycle unless we either nil out observer here OR
    // unless we use __weak in addition to __block. But what does the latter mean?
  }];
```

But I am having trouble parsing this. If `__block` causes the observer to be retained by the block, then what does it mean to effectively be both strong and weak? What is the `__weak` doing here?

Comment: `observer` will be uninitialized while block will be copied, so you can't reference it inside block anyway.

Comment: And `__weak` + `__block` means that variable is weak-referenced and can be changed by the code that is executed in the block.

Comment: First comment isn't quite correct, you can reference it if you know that the block won't execute before the assignment is done. (See also 8477629)

Comment: I guess the issue is that I'm just conflating __block and __strong in my head incorrectly. Is this an accurate assessment of the code above: neither the stack frame nor the block has a strong reference to the observer. The observer is only retained and kept alive by the notification center. So although the observer retains the block, there is no retain cycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__block` means that the variable is like global, that survives the current frame stack, and accessible by the block that you will declare in the scope.

`__weak` means that the variable doesn't retain the pointed object, but if the object gets deallocated the `__weak` pointer will be set to nil.

In your case observer catches the return value of addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: , so it doesn't need to be strong. And if was strong then it was retaining the observer, making it global and surviving until the strong reference was set to nil.

**Example**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void (^foo()) ()
{
    NSString* str= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"Hey"];
    __block __weak NSString* x= str;
    return ^
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",x);
    };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        void (^block) ()= foo();
        block();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example prints (null), let's see what happened:

- The string @"Hey" has 1 as ARC reference count;
- It is used in the block, but since it's weak it's not retained by the block, so it still has the count to 1;
- The block is returned and executed, since we exit from the foo function scope, the string is deallocated and the pointer x is set to nil.

So you could just do it like this:

```
void (^foo()) ()
{
    NSString* str= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"Hey"];
    return ^
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
    };
}
```

There's no problem: str is strong by default so it's captured, you don't need the __block specifier.

Comment: But per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html: "In ARC mode, __block id x; defaults to retaining x (just like all other values)"

Comment: I guess that just means it is retained as usual by the stack frame, NOT that it is retained by the block?

Comment: It defaults to retaining x, but with a __weak specifier it doesn't.

Comment: "In manual reference counting mode, __block id x; has the effect of not retaining x. In ARC mode, __block id x; defaults to retaining x (just like all other values). To get the manual reference counting mode behavior under ARC, you could use __unsafe_unretained __block id x;."

Comment: I guess this answers the question: "It defaults to retaining x, but with a __weak specifier it doesn't." It's just really confusing to have to keep in mind that __block now means retained under ARC, except when __weak is present, and then that takes precedence. In my mind, it reads like "__strong __weak".

Comment: Is it fair to say that, rather than being a synonym for __strong under ARC, __block instead simply has no effect on strong or weak anymore the way it used to in manual reference counting?

Comment: Hard to explain, see the example :-)